# ElasticSearch number of elements change when using filter and minScore

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am using a query like this:

Select all results for Keyword "X" with min_score = 0.25. Also I am doing aggregations for this results. But when I am clicking on an aggregation, the number of documents becomes different, because this min_score. When I remove the min_score, everything is fine.

What can I do, so I have ever the same count on the aggregations and on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html#_scoring_with_literal_bool_filter_literal

Use filter instead of must